# 500 internal server error when trying to implement reverse proxy under Apache. How do I forward the requests to another server without errors?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, proxy

I want to forward a request from one server to another. Here is my problem:

- `hr.example.com` - port 80 - Server A
- `support.example.com` - port 80 - Server B

All requests on port 80 are forwarded to Server A by the firewall.

So, I want requests for `support.example.com` to be forwarded from server A to server B. How can I achieve this with Apache?

I followed the answer from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/510758/how-to-pass-a-request-from-one-apache-server-to-another). I added the following code to my `apache.conf` on Server A but it results in a "500 internal server error".

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName support.example.com    
  LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so    
  ProxyRequests Off
  <Proxy *>
     Require all granted
  </Proxy>    
  ProxyPass / http://IP-ADDRESS-SERVER-B:80/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://IP-ADDRESS-SERVER-B:80/
  <Location />
     Require all granted
   </Location>    
</VirtualHost>
```

Note: Server A is Windows server 2012 with Apache 2.4

How should I forward these requests properly please?

Comment: You need to check your error log for the details of this error. You may also need mod_proxy_html. `IP-ADDRESS-SERVER-B` - Does this serve the content from `support.example.com`?

Comment: of course: `error.log`stated the following:`AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule` 
It turned out i needed extra module `mod_proxy_http`and now it's redirecting correctly to `IP-ADDRESS-SERVER-B`(which serve content of `support.example.com`.
Only problem now: it displays another webpage running on :80. How can I point it to correct site (`ServerName`is already correct`)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant mod_proxy_http (mod_proxy_html is another module but is not necessarily "essential"). "it displays another webpage" - if you have multiple vHosts on Server-B then you can't use the server's IP address, you must use the hostname.

Comment: Marvelous! It works indeed with the hostname. I'll make a new post with my working apache conf. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @MrWhite for giving the correct configuration. 
I needed extra module  `mod_proxy_http` and to change the IP adress of server-B to the hostname as I have multiple vHosts on :80.
Here is the working configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
support.example.com 
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so


 ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
     Require all granted
    </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://support.example.com:80/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://support.example.com:80/
  <Location />
       Require all granted
   </Location>


</VirtualHost>
```